# Can't Unwrap An Optional When Populating Cell

Tags: ios, swift

I hate to post this because it seems like basic Swift, however, I cannot find a way to get this optional unwrapped and I have an idea that it may be with the way NSUserDefaults is storing it, but I'm not sure.

I am saving an [String] as so:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(infectedNamesArray, forKey: "infectedNamesArray")
```

and recalling it like this:

```
if let infected = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("infectedNamesArray")
    {
        infectedNamesArray = infected as! [String]
    }
```

I am using the array to populate a reusable cell like this:

```
switch whichScoreSet
    {
    case 0:
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Test"
        cell.scoreLabel.text = "Test"
    case 1:
        cell.nameLabel.text = infectedNamesArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.scoreLabel.text = "\(infectedGameScoreTotals["\(infectedNamesArray[indexPath.row])"]!)"
    case 2:
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Test"
        cell.scoreLabel.text = "Test"
    default:
        print("Something Went Wrong")
    }
```

Everything works fine, I am able to switch between table data and load views.  When viewing the data from cell.nameLabel.text, it consistently displays optional. i.e. optional(valueFromArray)

I have tried to force unwrap it, and Xcode tells me I can't unwrap a string.  I have tried casting it as a string and Xcode tells me it would make no difference because it is already a string.

I am at a loss on this basic Swift, so please forgive the question.  Techniques from many other SO posts provide the same results.

What am I overlooking here?

EDITED

The variable is declared outside of a class as such.

```
var infectedNamesArray = [String]()
```

Comment: It depends on how `infectedNamesArray` is declared. If you declare it as non-optional empty array `var infectedNamesArray = [String]()` everything is going to be fine.

Comment: @vadian That is how I have it declared, which is why I'm thrown for a loop.

Comment: Where is `infectedNamesArray` defined? Can you post that code?

Comment: Also, is it showing up as `Optional(name)` in the actual application UI, or are you printing the value in the terminal?

Comment: @RomanSausarnes I edited the question to show my declaration code and the label in the cell is showing Optional(name), I am not printing it.

Comment: Show the code where you are adding the objects to `infectedNamesArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`infectedNamesArray[indexPath.row]` is supposed to be safe so you can use it directly

```
let infectedName = infectedNamesArray[indexPath.row] 
cell.nameLabel.text = infectedName
```

the value for key `infectedName` in `infectedGameScoreTotals` can be missing and is optional, so try

```
let scoreTotal = infectedGameScoreTotals[infectedName]
cell.scoreLabel.text = scoreTotal != nil ? "\(scoreTotal!)" : "n/a"
```

`n/a` is a placeholder to be displayed in case the dictionary key is no available.

Comment: I just tried this, everything still displays, but I am still getting the optional in the display.  Side note, thanks a ton for the much better way to display the dictionary value.

Comment: Then the dictionary `infectedGameScoreTotals` itself seems to be an optional. Try `infectedGameScoreTotals![infectedName]` or use optional binding.

Comment: The dictionary was displaying properly, the [String] was the one I was having issues with.

Comment: According to the code to read from user defaults the array can't be optional unless you are already saving optional strings via String Interpolation like `"Optional(whatever)"`

Comment: And... we have a winner.  I was loading data into the array via String Interpolation.  That caused it all to be muddled up.  Thank you for that and for the time answering!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
switch whichScoreSet
    {
    case 0:
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Test"
        cell.scoreLabel.text = "Test"
    case 1:
    if let nameString = infectedNamesArray[indexPath.row] as? String  {
        cell.nameLabel.text = nameString
        cell.scoreLabel.text = "\(infectedGameScoreTotals["\(nameString)"]!)"
   }
    case 2:
        cell.nameLabel.text = "Test"
        cell.scoreLabel.text = "Test"
    default:
        print("Something Went Wrong")
    }
```

Comment: This provided the same results I was having.  Nothing changed. I also get the warning that a conditional cast from String to String always succeeds.

Comment: Try replacing "?" with "!"

Comment: when I replace the ? with !, it gives me a red error saying it must have an optional type not a string type.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the nil coalescing operator and providing a default value, like this:

```
case 1:
    cell.nameLabel.text = infectedNamesArray[indexPath.row] ?? "Some Default String"
```

That should work to unwrap the optional `infectedNamesArray[indexPath.row]` and if it is `nil`, substitute the default `String`.

Comment: This didn't change anything as well.  I am still getting an optional when displayed.